# How to determine all the default ports used by Hadoop and change all of them?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, centos, port

I tried Hadoop 2 on a cluster of three virtual machines running CentOS 6.4.

And I launched the hadoop cluster successfully, though the configuration files of Hadoop 2 such as: [core-site.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml), [hdfs-site.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml), [mapred-site.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) and [yarn-site.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) tortures me a lot.

I want to change all the default ports used by Hadoop 2. The official documents of the configuration file has so many ports number defined. As a result, I think it is better to determine which ports used by Hadoop when it is running and then change all of them. So How can I find out all the default ports used by Hadoop in the cluster running CentOS? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the ports that a particular process has open by using the netstat command, combined with a little bash one liner. I don't have hadoop up on my machine at the moment, so here's an example to find out what port sshd is running on (should be 22!):

You'll need to know the process id of you hadoop processes (TT, JT, NN, DN etc), which can be found by doing another oneliner, so for my sshd example:

```
#> sudo ps axww | grep sshd
1065 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

You can replace sshd in the grep for hadoop and it will catch most of the processes running on that node.

Now we can use another one liner to find out what ports sshd has open for LISTENing (process id 1065):

```
#> sudo netstat -alpn | grep 1065 | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1065/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1065/sshd
```

You'll need to do this for all hadoop processes, on all nodes. Things like the data node and task tracker ports should match across machines, but only one node may have a name node / job tracker process running.